# Formalities for video submitted with paper?

Tags: citations, conference, paper-submission, audio-video-recording

A conference mentions "Supplementary material (images, video, etc.) may optionally be submitted with papers, must be submitted as a single zip file and be no larger than 100MB.".

So along with my conference paper, I'm considering submitting a video that shows the working of my program. Few questions:

1. I couldn't find any specific info on how to mention or cite in my paper that there is a video included with the paper as a supplementary file. Can I just mention "...in minute 2:05 of the video included as a  supplementary file..."?
2. Since the video has no audio, I'm considering adding to the video, some pleasant background music that's from a website which allows such music to be used royalty-free, but asks us to cite/attribute the creator of the music. So firstly, is it proper etiquette to use such music in a conference paper submission, and secondly, how would the attribution be mentioned? In a separate text file or as a citation in the paper itself? Also, is citing it enough, or do I have to explicitly obtain the creator's permission, in the same way, publishers ask for proof of copyright consent from the creators of images when I include somebody else's image in my paper (even after I've cited the source)?

Comment: A warning. Not a problem, but be aware that somebody, somewhere, will probably issue a takedown notice for you video because of the audio. It won't be correct, but it will probably happen. The US DCMA makes it too easy to issue such things inappropriately. Be prepared to respond, because the video _will_ be taken down unless you complain. And complaints might not even be listened to.

Comment: Well in that case, I could use a software that generates music. There are some such free DJ electronic music generators. Thanks for the timely word of caution.

Comment: I think you have given the answers to the question in the question.  If you don't put the video on a site known for music piracy (like YouTube) I doubt you will get any automated DMCA notices.

Comment: Can you specify the field? I do not see why you would submit a video edited to add music. Supplementary material for a paper is supposed (in my field) to be raw data, samples of program inputs, interview transcripts, etc. A video with added music would be in my view somewhat unprofessional or a PR stunt. (I have no objection whatsoever to adding music for a video you will show during the conference, but a presentation has a different purpose from supplementary materials)

Comment: Also (again from my understanding of supplementary materials) the paper should be readable without them. If what happens at 2:05 is particularly important to your argument, consider including an image or series of images in the main text. (I am aware that this is not always a workable solution.)

Comment: @UJM Thank you, and I agree with you that adding music may get interpreted as unprofessional. The thought had crossed my mind, and I'm glad you corroborated it. This is in the field of Computer Science. Specifically, Artificial Intelligence, where I've created a legged robot that climbs obstacles in a simulated physics environment.